# Is that caches or cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I was reading [google slide](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker-slides) on progressive Web apps where they mentioned cache interface has below methods

```
cache.add() 
cache.addAll()
cache..put()
cache.delete()
cache.keys()
cache.match()
cache.matchAll()
```

but in further slides in real implementation, they are using sometimes *cache**s*** ( with s ) and sometimes *cache*

```
caches.open()  // whereas this method was not mentioned anywhere

caches.keys() 
caches.delete()
caches.match()

cache.put () // only here using cache
```

Also, check for the same in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

they are writing Cache.add, Cache.addAll, and Cache.put  ( with capital c)

and using *caches.open* , *cache.match()* and other methods

I want to know does **cache** and **caches** are 2 different objects ( or interface ) or What I am lacking here?

Please provide some resources or links to know more about these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`window.caches` is a [`CacheStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) interface which stores all named [`Cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) objects. For example the `window.caches.open()` method returns a promise that resolves to a `Cache` object.

```
// Get a named Cache object from CacheStorage
window.caches.open('cachename').then(cache => {
    // Work with resolved cache object (instance of Cache)
});
```

So whenever they reference `caches`, they mean the global `CacheStorage` interface, while `cache` is and arbitrarily named variable storing an individual `Cache` that was opened/resolved.

Comment: You could make it even clearer by noting that then(cache => ... is arbitrarily named variable. then(myCache => ... is exactly same and naming it cache is just a convention.

Comment: Thank for for the beautiful anser but still not clear what means by individual cache?  what i understand is that `Caches = [{cache},{cache}]` is that correct?

Comment: individual Cache means what? The service worker cache or browser cache?

Comment: `Cache` object is a service worker cache. According to the docs you can use it in windowed scopes too, you don't need to have a service worker. You can have multiple `Cache` objects, they're all stored within the global `CacheStorage` interface (accessible via `window.caches`).

Comment: Thanks. But I am talking about service work and? it would be helpful if you provide me some valid reason why would I not use service-worker?

Comment: the link also is written *you don't have to use it with service workers, even though that is the spec that defines it*

Comment: @pro.mean Yes, that's what I said, I have nothing against service workers, I didn't say not to use them. I just mentioned that you can also use Cache without service workers.

Comment: oh yeah, I misunderstood for a while. Sorry for being aggressive on that. although I have edited that.;) btw [your website](http://codebin.co.uk/) is not showing anything. is that OK?

Comment: @pro.mean My web server was struggling for a bit, should be ok now. Thanks for the heads-up. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, caches store cache objects. Also quoting an example in the image attached (of Developer Tools in Google Chrome) from your link of [progressive Web apps](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker-slides)

[image: A list of cache under Cache Storage can be seen in Browser's Developer Tool]
To read more about caches, refer [CacheStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage).

(Because "You can access CacheStorage through the global caches property" so its one and the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Caches are tremendously useful in a wide variety of use cases. For example, you should consider using caches when a value is expensive to compute or retrieve, and you will need its value on a certain input more than once.

A Cache is similar to ConcurrentMap, but not quite the same. The most fundamental difference is that a ConcurrentMap persists all elements that are added to it until they are explicitly removed. A Cache on the other hand is generally configured to evict entries automatically, in order to constrain its memory footprint. In some cases a LoadingCache can be useful even if it doesn't evict entries, due to its automatic cache loading.

Comment: The question was about the difference (if any) between an object called `Cache` and an object called `Caches`, not about what a cache is

Comment: Thanks for the insight of cache but this is not what I am looking for.